# Filtering Moments in a PHAssetCollection

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

Using iOS 11 / Swift 4, I am trying to filter a collection of moments from a photo library.  I just want the `Places`.  Retrieving a collection of moments with `nil` options, I get 13 moments, with 8 moments having a non-nil title (location).  When I do the fetch moments with a simple predicate `localizedTitle != nil`, the result is always nil. Substituting an empty `String ("")` for the nil also yields an empty result.

Here is sample code and console results:

```
let momentOptions = PHFetchOptions()
momentOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"localizedTitle != nil")
momentList = PHAssetCollection.fetchMoments(with: nil)
let momentListFiltered = PHAssetCollection.fetchMoments(with: momentOptions)
let assetCount = momentList.count

for index in 0...assetCount-1 {
    let a = momentList[index]
    let sta = a.localizedTitle
    let stb = a.localizedLocationNames
    print(index, sta ?? "--", stb)
}
```

Results on Console:

```
0 -- []
1 -- []
2 Point Reyes National Seashore ["Point Reyes Station, CA"]
3 Þingeyjarsveit, Northeast Iceland ["Goðafossvegur"]
4 Djúpavogshreppur ["East Iceland"]
5 Rangárþing eystra ["South Iceland"]
6 New York - Washington Heights ["W 168th St"]
7 -- []
8 -- []
9 Jacksonville, NC ["Western Blvd"]
10 -- []
11 Locust Shade Park ["Triangle, VA"]
12 Piedmont Triad International Airport ["Friendship, NC"]

(lldb) po momentListFiltered
<PHFetchResult: 0x60c0002e2100> count=0
```

finally, just to confirm the correct comparison:

```
p momentList[7].localizedTitle == nil
(Bool) $R2 = true
```

Answer (score 3):

That does seem to be a bug or undocumented limitation in the Photos API. I would encourage you to submit a bug to Apple via the [Bug Reporter](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/).

You may find this alternate method useful:

```
let momentLists = PHCollectionList.fetchMomentLists(with: .momentListCluster, options: nil)
if momentLists.count > 0 {
    for index in 0...momentLists.count - 1 {
        let a = momentLists[index]
        print(index, a.localizedTitle ?? "--", a.localizedLocationNames)
    }
} else {
    print("-- No moment lists! --")
}
```

This gets a list of moment clusters, which seems to group photos by place and time.

Comment: Hi Dave!  Thanks for answer.  I did file a bug report as you suggest and we will see if something comes of it. I don't really see the advantage of using a collection list over a regular collection as in my example. They are both immutable, so to make a tableview of places, i would need to be messy and create an array from the collection, then got back to the original unfiltered collection to acquire the assets when a table entry is tapped. There must be a better way!

Comment: I think the advantage is that `PHCollectionList` might get you the place colections that you're after, while `PHAssetCollection` does not since you can't filter them. :) Even if Apple acknowledges your bug the earliest it would be fixed is in iOS 12.